# node-oracledb connection to Exacc database via TCPS

Tags: database, oracle, tcpserver, truststore, node-oracledb

I use Protractor where I'm doing some tests. I need to connect to Oracle Database. We've just migrated to ExaCC Oracle database but I can't connect to this database with node-oracledb via TCPS protocol.

I have a 'cacerts' file as trustStore and password to it. What I try to do is:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

const connectionConfig = {
  user: 'my_username',
  password: 'my_password',
  connectString: 'my_connection_string',
  externalAuth: false, 
  ssl: {
    trustStore: 'path/to/my/cacerts',
    trustStorePassword: 'my_password_to_cacerts'
  }
};
```

Unfortunatelly if I run my protractor test and it tries to connect to database I get:

```
ORA-28759: failure to open file
```

Can somebody advice how this connections should look like in case of Exacc connections?

Comment: Update your post with more details: what is using the `ssl` attributes you set in `connectionConfig`?  What is in your sqlnet.ora file?  Does your connection string use a tcps prefix?

Comment: I still don't know what you are trying to do, but NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS may be something else to investigate once you fix your ORA-28759 issue.